# RFID race timing system using raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid

I would like to build a race timing system using UHF RFID passive tags. I have seen self build systems described as per the following link which is being used in races with apparent success:

http://www.letsrun.com/forum/flat_read.php?thread=5518905

The major cost of such a system seems to be the rfid reader, so I wondered whether it would be possible to achieve similar results by substituting the commercial uhf readers listed with multiple raspberry pi 2b devices andlong range uhf reader module?

Is this realistic? What are likely to be the problems, constraints or deficiencies when compared to the commercial rfid readers?

Comment: I seem to recall that TrolleyPonder  implemented a race timing system.  Commercial and perhaps more expensive than DIY but they have been serving difficult niche markets for over 10 years.  -  http://www.rfid-radar.com/